# Index an array with constants with Turbo C++ inline asm

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, inline-assembly, turbo-c++

I'm trying to write 16-bit inline assembly code in the Turbo C++ 3.0 IDE. I need to access an array defined in a high level language like *C++* using inline assembly but my attempts have failed. Code that fails to compile:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
       int array[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};
       asm{
           mov ax,array[0]
       }
       // fall off the end of the function with return value in AX
       // Or else C++ implicit return 0 still happens.
}
```

The code above gives me an error on the instruction `mov ax,array[0]`:

> Invalid combination of opcode and operands

I tried to go through manual of Turbo C++ 3.0 to learn how to copy the contents but there was no information about how to do it with inline assembly.

I've even gone through the *8086 to Pentium* assembly language book but nowhere could I find the answer to my question.

When I try other ways I seem to get incorrect answers like -22, instead of 1.

(Editor's note: it isn't clear whether the OP was looking at AX with a debugger or just looking at the return value of `main`.)

Comment: Nobody remembers that. How about you switch to something from this millenium? :) Anyway, try `mov ax, [array]`. Verify generated assembly code.

Comment: Or `mov ax, WORD PTR [array]`. Also check what size is `int` there, 16-bit or 32-bit

Comment: @Renat : In Turbo-C (Borland) and other similar 16-bit compilers (16-bit Microsoft, Watcom, Zortech) `int` is 16-bit, `short int` is 16-bit, `long` is 32-bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing elements of arrays that were generated on the stack can be a bit tricky. The compiler generates memory references relative to register *BP* when accessing stack based variables (ie: non-static variables defined on the stack like `array`). Your instruction:

```
mov ax,array[0]
```

will give an error:

> Invalid combinations of opcodes and operands

That syntax doesn't work for stack variables including arrays. What will work is:

```
mov ax,[array]     ; Get first int in array
mov ax,[array+2]   ; Get second int in array
mov ax,[array+4]   ; Get third int in array
```

The use of `[0]` doesn't work in inline assembly like it does in *C* code. You have to compute the byte address of each element of the array, thus the reason why `[array+2]` points at the second element, and `[array+4]` points at the third element in the array. The developer has to scale the offset being added based on the size of an element. If `array` was an array of `char` then `[array+1]` points at the second element, and `[array+2]` points at the third element in the array. With an array of `long` (32-bit value) `[array+4]` points at the second element, and `[array+8]` points at the third element in the array.

Your inline assembly could have looked like this to access the third element of the `int` array:

```
asm{
    mov ax, [array+4]
};
```

Normally, when dealing with arrays you may want to access more than one element, or create a loop to do some operations on a number of the elements. In that case you will want to consider loading the address of the array into a register like *SI*<sup>1</sup>. Once you have the address of the array you can access individual elements. Once you have the address of the array you can add the byte offset to the element (`int` in this case) and retrieve the value. If the address of the array is placed in *SI* then `[si+0]` (or `[si]`) is the address of the first integer in the array.

To retrieve the address of a stack variable or a global variable you can use the [`LEA`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/lea) instruction (Load Effective Address). The following code uses `LEA` to get the address of the base (element 0) of `array` into *SI*. The code retrieves the value of the 3rd integer element (`array+4`) and places it in *AX*. The code then sets another variable `myint` with the value in *AX*. The *C* code then prints the value. The example code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int array[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};
    int myint;

    asm{
        lea si, [array]
        mov ax, [si+4]             ; Get third int element from the array
        mov [myint], ax
    };

    printf("Third element: %d\n", myint);
    return 0;
}
```

Should produce this as output:

> Third element: 3

---

If you wanted to sum all the integers in the array then inline assembly could look like:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int array[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};
    /* arrsize = number of ints in array */
    const unsigned int arrsize = sizeof(array)/sizeof(int);
    int total;

    asm{
        /* Sum a non-zero length array from the last element down to first element */
        lea si, [array]        /* SI = base address of array */
        mov bx, [arrsize]      /* BX = Number of 16-bit ints in array */
        shl bx, 1              /* BX = BX * 2 = length of array in bytes
                                  BX points at element just beyond the end of the array */
        xor ax, ax             /* AX = current sum = 0 */
    }
    numloop:
    asm{
        add ax, [si+bx-2]      /* Add current element */
        sub bx, 2              /* BX =  position of previous element in array */
        jnz numloop            /* If the index = 0 then we aren't finished */

        mov [total], ax        /* Move the sum into variable total */
    };

    printf("Sum of all ints: %d\n", total);
    return 0;
}
```

Some versions of Turbo-C don't properly support labels inside inline assembly statements. Instead, you can use *C* labels that are usually used for the `goto` statement in *C*. You just have to break up your inline assembly into multiple parts to place the label where necessary as is done with label `numloop` in the example above.

The output should be:

> Sum of all ints: 45

---

### Footnotes:

- <sup>1</sup>*BX*, *DI*, and *SI* are registers that are allowed in [16-bit addressing modes](http://service.scs.carleton.ca/sivarama/asm_book_web/Instructor_copies/ch5_addrmodes.pdf). *BP* is also allowed but it implicitly uses *SS* as the segment rather than *DS*.